# Hibernate Criteria for sum(distinct clicks)

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, hibernate-criteria

I am unable to come up with the criteria which can perform **sum(distinct clicks)** in query. I am getting result with simple sql query but cannot make criteria to do the same.

Currently i can just do

```
    .add(Projections.property("clicks").as("clicks"))
```

A simple sql query is like this

select **sum(distinct clicks) as clicks**, source as source, sum(jobs_sent) as jobsSent from tbl_click_count where date= '2016-09-04' and domain = 'somename'  and whitelabel = 'somename'  group by source, whitelabel, domain  order by id desc

and my criteria is like

```
    Criteria criteria = getSessionFactory().createCriteria(FeedClickCountModel.class)
     .add(Restrictions.ge("date", startDate))
     .add(Restrictions.le("date", uptoDate))
     .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
     .add(Projections.sum("jobsSent").as("jobsSent"))
     .add(Projections.groupProperty("source").as("source"))
     .add(Projections.property("whiteLabel").as("whiteLabel"))
     .add(Projections.property("domain").as("domain"))
     .add(Projections.property("totalJobs").as("totalJobs"))

     .add(Projections.property("clicks").as("clicks"))
     // ^This i want is sum(distinct clicks)

     .add(Projections.property("date").as("date"))
     .add(Projections.property("id").as("id")))
     .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(FeedClickCountModel.class));
```

Is there any way to do this without sqlprojection.

Answer (score 0):

```
.add(Projections.distinct(Projections.property("clicks")));
```

Like this?

Comment: Hi, I updated question with code for better understanding of requirement. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
Projections.sum(Projections.countDistinct(propertyName));
```

Try this.

Without projections, you will need to use hibernate SQL or native SQL queries.

Comment: It give cast exception ...."The method sum(String) in the type Projections is not applicable for the arguments (CountProjection)".... I am using native sql solved it. Though it would had been better if it could be done by criteria.